# easyMP3Gain: Error: Cannot start aacgain

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, aac

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and trying to adjust the volume of my aac music files using easyMP3Gain, but lamentably getting an error I cannot fix.

Exact version: easymp3gain-gtk 0.5.0+svn135-4

Status message in the GUI app when I open an aac file:

> Error: Cannot start aacgain...

I cannot find any other package that might be necessary to get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install the "aacgain - 1.9-1~trusty+1" package from [Stefano's personal repository](https://launchpad.net/~stefanobalocco/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages)!

Note: You may get another error saying "Unknown Media Type: ...", which means that your file needs to be in a meta data supporting container format (m4a, mp4 etc.)

I since moved on to Xubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn, but as of yet there's no ready-made package available for it. You can simply download the one for Trusty and change the second line in `./DEBIAN/control` from `Version: 1.9-1~trusty+1` to `Version: 1.9-1~utopic+1`. If you had to extract the deb archive you can put it back together like this:

```
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build aacgain_1.9-1~utopic+1_i386/ aacgain_1.9-1~utopic+1_i386.deb
```